# Mouse does not work properly after suspension

Tags: mouse, touchpad, suspend

After suspending my laptop, the touchpad and the usb mouse will not work properly.
The cursor can move, but the buttons cannot be clicked.

but if I remove the corresponding modules and install them again, everything is fine.

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo rmmod usbhid
```

then

```
sudo insmod /... #install the psmouse module
sudo insmod /... #install usb mouse module
```

It's OK again.

Who can tell my how to make it right?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

create a script to run when awake from suspend

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/mouse
```

Add copy following text in the script

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    resume)
        modprobe -r psmouse
        modprobe psmouse
esac
```

as any script in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` runs as root your problem should be solved